# .NET Core doesn't return OData metadata in Responses on Swagger

Tags: .net-core, swagger, odata, swagger-net

I'm using swagger in order to generate the endpoints for my React app. In order to do that, I need to specify the response objects for my endpoints and one of my endpoints that has `[EnableQuery]` annotation, which means is an OData endpoint placed inside an ODataController, doesn't return the right format. What I return now is

```
{
  "ODataContext": "string",
  "ODataCount": 0,
  "ODataNextLink": "string",
  "Value": List<Project>
}
```

instead of

```
{
  "@odata.context": "string",
  "@odata.count": 0,
  "@odata.nextLink": "string",
  "value": List<Project>
}
```

I followed this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/513) from GitHub and the code I used is

```
[EnableQuery(PageSize = ITEMS_PER_PAGE)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ODataValueWithCount<IEnumerable<Project>>), 200)]
public IQueryable<Project> GetAsync()
{
    return _projectRepository.GetProjects();
}
```

```
internal class ODataValueWithCount<T> : ODataValue
{
    [JsonProperty("@odata.context")]
    public string ODataContext { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@odata.count")]
    public int ODataCount { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@odata.nextLink")]
    public string ODataNextLink { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public List<Project> Value { get; set; }
}
```

```
private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<Project>("Projects");
    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

but this still somehow returns me the first object that I noted here even though the solution from the issue seems as it's working there. Do you know what am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?
More code from `Startup.cs`:

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "MyAPI V1");
});

services.AddSwaggerGen(swagger =>
{
    swagger.OperationFilter<ODataOperationFilter>();
    swagger.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "API", Version = "0.0.1" });
    swagger.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "Please insert JWT with Bearer into field",
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
    });
    swagger.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement 
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                    {
                        Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                        Id = "Bearer"
                    }
            },
        new string[] { }
        }
    });
    swagger.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescription => apiDescription.First());
});
```

Comment: OData has its own metadata and schema format, just like GraphQL. They don't use Swagger/OpenAPI. OData clients and proxies understand and expect the OData metadata, not Swagger. The Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData package does emit Swagger though provided you enable Swagger generation for the overall project. What does your `Startup.cs` look like? Have you added `AddSwaggerGen` and `UseSwagger` ?

Comment: Yes @PanagiotisKanavos, I have them added. I updated the question and added a new code snippet at the end. But I don't think that's the problem, if I call the endpoint directly I get the right metadata format with odata.context, odata.count etc. What I'm having difficulties with is that I cannot find a way to embed this as a response object on Swagger so my front-end app generator can pick it up and expect that type of object.

Comment: @anthino12 you should use `JsonPropertyName` instead of `JsonProperty` to override names in swagger schema